# Overloading __getitem__ enum Python to return the first element of a tuple

Tags: python, enums

I wanted to overload the **getitem** Enum method in Python to return the first element of a tuple instead of the whole value content. For that, I tried to create an Enum based in the EnumMeta with the redefined method, just like below, and then the Enum final class inheriting from it, just like it's shown below:

```
from enum import Enum
from enum import EnumMeta
from datetime import date

class CommandMeta (EnumMeta):
    SUCCESS = 0, "Exited successsssfully."

    def __getitem__(cls, value, *args, **kwargs):
        value = value[0]
        return super().__getitem__(value, *args, **kwargs)

class Command (Enum, metaclass=CommandMeta):
    SUCCESS = 0, "Exited successsssfully."
```

The expected output was:

```
print(Command.SUCCESS.value)
0
```

And instead, it is still the same:

```
print(Command.SUCCESS.value)
(0, 'Exited successsssfully.')
```

How could I manage to overload the method properly?

Comment: You are misguided, read up on [object.__getitem__](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__)

Comment: Thank you for answering, I pressume then that what I should do is letting value=cls[value]?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation on enums gives a [good example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#planet) of how to store multiple constants on an enum, and access them via attribute name.

```
class Planet(Enum):
    MERCURY = (3.303e+23, 2.4397e6)
    VENUS   = (4.869e+24, 6.0518e6)
    EARTH   = (5.976e+24, 6.37814e6)
    MARS    = (6.421e+23, 3.3972e6)
    JUPITER = (1.9e+27,   7.1492e7)
    SATURN  = (5.688e+26, 6.0268e7)
    URANUS  = (8.686e+25, 2.5559e7)
    NEPTUNE = (1.024e+26, 2.4746e7)
    def __init__(self, mass, radius):
        self.mass = mass       # in kilograms
        self.radius = radius   # in meters
    @property
    def surface_gravity(self):
        # universal gravitational constant  (m3 kg-1 s-2)
        G = 6.67300E-11
        return G * self.mass / (self.radius * self.radius)
```

Which looks like this when accessed:

```
>>> Planet.EARTH.value
(5.976e+24, 6378140.0)
>>> Planet.EARTH.mass
5.976e+24
>>> Planet.EARTH.surface_gravity
9.802652743337129
```

Answer (score 0):

`Command.SUCCESS` and `SUCCESS.value` are all attribute accesses, so `__getitem__` never enters the picture.

If you want the `value` to be `0` (or `1`, etc.) then you want to split `0, "Exited successsssfully"` into two parts -- maybe [`value` and `__doc__`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52063239/208880)?  To see something similar, only done with the stdlib `Enum`, try [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41489612/208880).

As far as subclassing `EnumMeta`, [please read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43730305/when-should-i-subclass-enummeta-instead-of-enum/43730306?r=SearchResults&s=23|44.8696#43730306).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a new metaclass for this, just ordinary inheritance. `__getitem__` is only invoked when you use index syntax.

```
class IndexableEnum(Enum):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.value[key]

class Command(IndexableEnum):
    SUCCESS = 0, "Exited successfully"
```

Then

```
>>> Command.SUCCESS
<Command.SUCCESS: (0, 'Exited successfully')>
>>> Command.SUCCESS[0]
0
```

(Of course, a class inheriting from `IndexableEnum` should have values that are, in fact, indexable, and `__getitem__` can be defined directly in your `Command` class if you don't plan on making multiple classes indexable.)